# Is it possible to loop through operators (greater than/less than) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, operators

I want to be able to loop through relational operators. I have the following code working:

```
TP = df[(df.Truth == 1) & eval(df.age >= cutoff)]
```

I have a few more of these lines where the truth value and the relational operator is different but everything else is the same.
I tried creating a list and using the eval function, but I know that's wrong since I can't even get past the syntax error.

```
truths = [[1,'>='],[0,'>='],[1,'<'],[0,'<']]
for truth in truths:
     truth_val = truth[0]
     operator = truth[1]
     TP = df[(df.Truth == truth) & eval(df.age operator cutoff)]
```

How do I go about looping the relational operator and not having python take it in as a string but as an actual operator?
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the actual operators, then you should use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) library:

```
import operator as op
```

Then your code should look like this:

```
truths = [[1, op.ge], [0, op.ge], [1, op.lt], [0, op.lt]]
for truth in truths:
  truth_val = truth[0]
  operator = truth[1]
  TP = df[(df.Truth == truth) & operator(df.age, cutoff)]
```

This is the safest solution, all solutions based on `eval` are heavily discouraged, evaluating strings at runtime is a potential security issue.

Comment: It works, Thank you! I never knew about this operator function.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
truths = [[1,'>='],[0,'>='],[1,'<'],[0,'<']]
for truth in truths:
     truth_val = truth[0]
     operator = truth[1]
     TP = df[(df.Truth == truth) & eval("df.age"+ operator + cutoff)] # notice cutoff here should be string
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up using the operator function, but I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `eval()` with a string:

```
truths = [[1,'>='],[0,'>='],[1,'<'],[0,'<']]
for truth in truths:
     truth_val = truth[0]
     operator = truth[1]
     print(eval(f"{df.age}{operator}{cutoff}"))
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up using the operator function, but I appreciate your help!